# Style html checkboxes without IDs and labels

Tags: html, css, checkbox

So I am using HTML checkboxes to create collapsible comment trees. The HTML and CSS code is fairly simple.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hide-box">
<div class="hidable">
    Example<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hide-box">
        <div class="hidable">
        Example
```

CSS:

```
.hide-box:checked~.hidable { display:none; }
```

My issue comes when I try to use a stylized checkbox. Every method I find to stylize a checkbox with CSS requires each checkbox to have a unique id which is matched to a "for=" in the checkbox label.

I'm going to be adding hundreds of these to several html documents with a mass find and replace, so I don't want to have to set up some kind of script to give each one a unique name.

Is there any method of stylizing the checkboxes that does not require giving each one a unique id? Preferably the solution would not require an javascript or jquery, I want to stick to html and css.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "stylized" boxes? Can't you just use classes? <input type="checkbox" class="hide-box stylized"> and .stylized { my_styles_here }

Comment: Can you modify your markup? I've got a solution that is pretty bulletproof, but requires wrappers around the inputs.

Comment: Yeah, if you have another solution that works better, by all means please let me know. I'm not particularly attached to this method, but I do want to keep it entirely to CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute selector to access all checkboxes. 
Then use id to access specific checkboxes that need to override the general style used for all checkboxes.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    // General styles for all checkboxes here
}
#specific-checkbox-id {
    // Specific styles here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer. My problem is that most things I have attempted have no affect. Would you happen to know what types of styles are valid to apply to checkboxes with this method?

Comment: Forms elements (ie, checkboxes) are particularly difficult to style - especially across different browsers.

If you need to create many style changes, the best option is to hide the display of the checkbox and replace it with a styled element of your own. In this case, make sure to use the `:checked` selector to display the state of the hidden checkbox.

Comment: Every method I have seen of doing that requires unique ids and labels for each checkbox, which as I stated I need to avoid. If you know a way of accomplishing that without each checkbox needing unique portions of code, then that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a class to all of your checkboxes and styling them using that class?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hide-box my-style">
<div class="hidable">
Example<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="hide-box my-style">
<div class="hidable"> 
Example
<input type="checkbox" class="my-style"> <!-- This won't have the hide logic-->
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide-box:checked~.hidable {
    display:none;
}

.my-style {
    // Insert your styles here
}
```